# html button, the value="submit" is not showing up?

Tags: html, css, button

I am looking for the value="submit" to show up in the middle of the button.  I am not seeing any text, not sure why?

```
<button type="button" class="button btn_big_blue" value="Submit"></button>

.button{
    display: block;
    width: 137px;
    height:    44px;
    text-align:center;
    line-height: 40px;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-decoration: none;
    color:#fff;
    border:none;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.button.btn_big_blue {
    background: url(/img/btn_big_blue.png) no-repeat;
    color: #fff;
}
```

Answer (score 12):

when you use the button tag, you put the text you want to be in the button between the opening and closing tag.

```
<button>Submit</button>
```

the `value="Submit"` is only for `<input type="button"`>

Comment: And for `<input type="submit" />` (or `reset`)

Answer (score 3):

The `<button>` tag doesn't use the `value` attribute.

You should either switch to an `<input type="submit" value="..." />` or move the caption to the content of the tag.

Comment: @Xtian: On the contrary - it's awesome.  It allows you put arbitrary content, such as images, in your `<button>` s.

Answer (score 1):

`value` is the value transmitted when submitting/sending the form.

you want to put your content between the button tags:

```
 <button class="button …">Submit</button>
```

ps. the class button seems pretty useless, because you can style the button directly

Answer (score 0):

For some reason on Atom, you need to include / after the Submit as such:

Whereas the same thing in codepen displays the Submit value without the slash as such:

```
<input type="Submit">
```